# Parallel Algorithm: Checking if a pixel is covered by one of the shapes

Tags: algorithm, matlab, parallel-processing, geometry

There is a map in 2-d space coordinates are from leftPos to rightPos in x axis, and from bottomPos to topPos in y axis.

There are shapes in this map: triangles, circles, squares. There are total of N shapes. I am trying to count to pixels if its inside any shapes. Shapes can overlap, and thus may have intersection areas.

My code is:

```
% paintedPixel is initialized to all zeroes

for i=1:1:N
    for j=leftPosition:1:rightPosition
       for k=bottomPos:1:topPos
           if (isInside(point(j,k), shape(i)) ) 
                paintedPixel[j,k] = 1;

       done
    done
 done
```

so I am trying to parallelize this code but only I can change the last *for* to *parfor*. 
 For the outher *for* s, MATLAB complains that k is not fixed. I understand that there might be race condition in general, but this particular case, I am just trying to assign if any of the shapes cover the given pixel.

So my question how to paralelize this ? I tried to put shape for to innermost, but MATLAB gives error saying that **paintexPixel in parfor cannot be classified**

Comment: I suggest you to paint all shapes in once in an image as binary masks, then count how many pixels are on. You get rid of one loop, it is way more faster since you scan pixels only once (and not N times). Maybe you can parallelize the loop which draws each shape...

Comment: you mean manually paint in Photosop kind of a program? I did not quite understand. But the shapes are being generated dynamically each time.

Comment: No, you can draw shapes in matlab. I don't know what is the format of your shapes, but if it is a sequence of points, you can draw each filled shapes in a binary image with [`roipoly`](http://www.mathworks.fr/fr/help/images/ref/roipoly.html)

Answer (score 1):

When you parallelize code with `parfor`, you need to be able to split the resulting array among the workers, so that every worker gets its own bit of the output that is completely independent of any other worker's bit.

In your case, all workers are writing to the same pixels, so it's not clear for Matlab which pixels should go to which workers. Thus the error message.

If you have the memory available, you can instead make `paintedPixel` into a `jks` array, so that every worker fills out its own array, which you can combine once the loop is done.

```
paintedPixelPerShape = false(nPosJ, nPosK, N); %# logical for less memory

parfor i=1:1:N
    for j=leftPosition:1:rightPosition
       for k=bottomPos:1:topPos
           if (isInside(point(j,k), shape(i)) ) 
                paintedPixelPerShape(j,k,i) = true;
           end
       end
    end
end

%# turn on any pixel that has been covered by at least one shape
paintedPixels = any(paintedPixelsPerShape,3);
```

Comment: In addition, you may be able, of course, to simplify the double loop.

Comment: The code you wrote makes perfect sense to me, I put that code but Matlab still complains that  paintedPixelPerShape in a parfor cannot be classified.